# how to get form values into state object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get the form values into an object but I can not get the values from form into the address object,

```
this.state = {
        address: {
            country: "",
            street: "",
            postcode: "",
            city: "",
        }
}


handle_form_input = ev => {
    debug("handle_form_input", ev)
    this.setState({
        [ev.target.name]: ev.target.value
    } as Form)
}

                   K(FormField, {
                        p, s,
                        type: "text",
                        name: "firstname",
                        onInput: this.handle_form_input
                   }),
                   K(FormField, {
                        p, s, type: "text", name: "country", onInput: this.handle_form_input
                    }),

                    K(FormField, {
                        p, s, type: "text", name: "street", onInput: this.handle_form_input
                    }),

                    K(FormField, {
                        p, s, type: "text", name: "plz", onInput: this.handle_form_input
                    }),

                    K(FormField, {
                        p, s, type: "text", name: "city", onInput: this.handle_form_input
                    }),

                    K("input", { type: "submit", hidden: true })
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to alter `state.address[ev.target.name]` and not just  `state[ev.target.name]`

```
handle_form_input = ev => {
  const { name, value } = ev.target;
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const address = { ...prevState.address };
    address[name] = value;
    return { address };
  });
};
```

Comment: thanks for a quick answer, how can I get the first name as well as the address, can I just use the [ev.target.name]: ev.target.value for the first name?

Comment: @akano1 You're welcome! If you have fields outside of `address` it's most likely best to create a second function to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You do great job, pushing values from from all together with their form names,
but those form names on state object are contained inside address object so the way forward is when you're pushing those values into a form you should say value name as found on address object as below

```
    this.setState({address[ev.target.name]: ev.target.value})
```

Comment: make sure there is a method to call when each field is edited **` address[ev.target.name]: ev.target.value`** should not be called on form submit if there is more than one form fields